# How to make click mat-tab click?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I have a mat tabs:

```
 <mat-tab *ngFor="let template of templateTypes" (click)="toggleSelectedTab(template.type)"></mat-tab>
```

It does not emit click event. I have tried to use embadded span:

```
 <mat-tab *ngFor="let template of templateTypes" (click)="toggleSelectedTab(template.type)">
            <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                <span (click)="toggleSelectedTab(template.type)"> {{ template.name }} ({{ template?.count }})</span>
            </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```

But `span` element has no fulll tab clickable area, it works as inline element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It starts from index 0 to the number of tabs you create.

In your html

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
     <mat-tab *ngFor="let template of templateTypes" 
              (click)="toggleSelectedTab(template.type)"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

In component use this code

```
tabChanged = (tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void => {
    console.log('tabChangeEvent => ', tabChangeEvent); 
    console.log('index => ', tabChangeEvent.index); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `div` instead of `span` and adjust it to fill the container using css

Comment: I have tried this:

`mat-tab div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}`